# Scrapy Ajax call not working

Tags: python, ajax, post, scrapy

im trying to crawl this page:http://www.tyrepac.com.sg/Form/B2C/FittingLocation.aspx

There's this data table which contains information that i want to crawl. like name & address.
However, it only display an area at a time Eg ( North, east ,west, south ).

When u select the area from the drop down list, a POST request is being called and the data will be displayed.

Here's my code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
import re
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
import json

from tyres.items import TyrePacItem

class TyrePacSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "tyrepac"
allowed_domains = ["tyrepac.com.sg"]
start_urls = ["http://www.tyrepac.com.sg/Form/B2C/FittingLocation.aspx"]

def start_requests(self):
    return FormRequest(
    url="http://www.tyrepac.com.sg/Form/B2C/FittingLocation.aspx",
    method='POST',
    formdata={'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cpFittingLocationDdl$cpRegion$ddlRegion': 'North'},
    callback=self.after_post
    )

def after_post(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    values = hxs.select('//table[@class="dxgvTable"][1]/tr')
    for value in values:
        item = TyrePacItem()
        #name = value.select('.//label[@class="dxeBase"][1]//text()').extract()
        #item['name'] = ' '.join(name)
        address = value.select('.//label[@class="dxeBase"][2]//text()').re('[^\n\t\r]+')
        item['address'] = ' '.join(address)
        # item['postal'] = item['address'][-6:]
        # hours = value.select('.//label[@class="dxeBase"][5]//text()').re('[^\n\t\r]+')
        # hours = ' '.join(hours)
        # item['hours'] = re.sub('\s+', ' ',hours)
        yield item
```

---

Traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg
\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 138, in _run_command
            cmd.run(args, opts)
          File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg
\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 44, in run
            self.crawler.crawl(spider)
          File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg
\scrapy\crawler.py", line 47, in crawl
            return self.engine.open_spider(spider, requests)
          File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\twisted-13.0.0-py2.7-wi
n32.egg\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1213, in unwindGenerator
            return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\twisted-13.0.0-py2.7-wi
n32.egg\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1070, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send(result)
          File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg
\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 220, in open_spider
            slot = Slot(start_requests, close_if_idle, nextcall, scheduler)
          File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.5-py2.7.egg
\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 27, in __init__
            self.start_requests = iter(start_requests)
        exceptions.TypeError: 'FormRequest' object is not iterable
```

Why is this happening and how can i solve it? 
Thx in advance

Comment: `meta` in `Requests` is used to pass data to callbacks, not data to be sent with HTTP requests. Try using `FormRequest()` with `formdata` argument. [See Scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-to-send-data-via-http-post) for an example